# Hide part of a string in EditText (Java/Android)

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, substring

Is it possible to hide part of a string in the editText with a method like

```
editText.hide(int start, int finish);
```

so that in the display I can't read the hidden part of the string, but if I use a method like `editText.getText()` in the code, it will include the hidden string?

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? As in asterisk out?

Comment: @PPartisan i want not see part of a string in the editText in my app... but this part of string is however inside the text of the EditText in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can do something like:**

```
String wholeString = editText.getText().toString();
editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().substring(int start, int end));
```

where start and end are integers that you want your string to begin and end at the positions you set.

So now you have the whole string before it was hidden. Additionally, if you want to hide a certain part in the middle of your editText, you can do something like this:

```
editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().substring(0, 20) + editText.getText().toString().substring(25, 30));
```

where you set your editText text with many strings. This will hide the string from position 21 till 25. You have to modify it according to your needs.

You may also need to know a method for a string called lastIndexOf("Some Text")

**Example:**

```
//You have a string called example.
String example = "Android development is fun and nice."
String cutExample = example.substring(example.lastIndexOf("is") +3, example.lastIndexOf(".");
```

The result will be: `"fun and nice"`.

So `lastIndexOf()` will return the position of the defined string.

Test with what I wrote. Hope that helps.

Comment: i have the editText that is the display of a calculator, and i have imposed that if before i click PiGreco button there's a number then display show me " x Pigreco" instead of "Pigreco". this because my calc method code needs to find operator to calculate the expressions (i can't write "8Pigreco" but "8 x Pigreco"). so I want that in the EditText in my code i have " x " to allow my method to work, but at the same time i want that the calculator display show me "8Pigreco" intead of "8 x Pigreco".

Comment: In your case, you have a different situation, you will need to create integers like **number1** and **number2** and a string for the **operator**, then do your code. This is how it is done. You can search on the internet for a calculator tutorial. There are plenty of them.

Comment: I have already done number button and calculator method, so what i want is to see in the display "8Pigreco"  while in the text of the EditText i have "8 x Pigreco"

Comment: It is like if i have this string "hello everyone" and i want that in the display i see "hello" but in the code the value of the string remain "hello everyone"

Comment: If you can post your code so far, I will be able to help you, otherwise search on google for a calculator tutorial as I said... :)

Comment: Is simple the question... thinks that  i have an editText with text value "hello everyone" and I want that in the editText in my app i see "hello" but the value in the code of editText remains "hello everyone"... is possible?

Comment: I have an idea... to print "everyone" at the same color of editText Background, so i cal see only "hello"... but there's something better? (Remain the space of "everyone" length..)

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi I think what you're trying to do is (in an abstract sense) too big for one "thing". You want the same string to have two different meanings. But strings are "small." They can only mean one thing at a time. Why not have a "real" string for internal calculations, and another "pretty" one for displaying to the user? If you prefer, the user can type in the "real" stuff, and then you can continually copy it to the real string, then convert the user input to the "pretty" stuff.

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi (P.S. I use small words not to demean you, but to help me focus on & express more of the nature of the problem, and less of the details.)

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi If you want to hide some part from your string, then you should use my answer, but if you are going to make a calculator, then you should check something like this: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-calculator-app-for-android/28100 People who make calculators don't hide the string, they just reset the text once the user enters an operator and at the same time the app gets the operand or number1 in a separate string before it is reset.

Comment: @jpaugh that's great! Thanks for your suggestion!!

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi This is what I said in this line in my answer "So now you have the whole string before it was hidden." You have the whole string before it was hidden, and at the same time, you have already hidden part of the string... :)

Comment: Oh sorry you have reason!! Thanks for your answer! !

Comment: do you had published your calculator app on google play so i can install on my device?

Comment: I'm still working on it, I haven't published it yet. It's mainly a GPA Calculator, but I have also added a normal calculator with it, so I can tell you when I publish it. I won't forget. ;)

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Just in case you want to see my app, here is the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.husseinelfeky.gpacalculator I hope it helps you. :)

Comment: above cod edoesn't give the answer for this question. editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().substring(0, 20) + editText.getText().toString().substring(25, 30)); after setting text in edittext and retriving i am getting only the text set in it not the whole one

Comment: @Vicky You need to get the text in a new String first before setting the new string so that you can get the old saved string anytime you want.